# getting unexpected value error from the np.dot

Tags: python

in one of my functions, I called the diff()

```
diffs = Tranche.diff(tranche_face, rate, new_rates)
```

```
# class level method of diff inside Tranche class
    @classmethod
    def diff(cls, tranche_face, last_rates, new_rates):
        step1 = [x - y for x, y in zip(last_rates, new_rates)]
        step2 = [abs(x / y) for x, y in zip(step1, last_rates)]
        return np.dot(tranche_face, step2) / sum(tranche_face)  # np.dot is from numpy
```

Below is the parameter getting passed-in:

```
tranche_face = [22683499.454199996, 5670874.863549999]
rate = [0.05, 0.08]
new_rates = [0.07061657282343299, 0.06874103335919428]
```

And I am getting the below error for diff:

```
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (4,) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Below is the functionality I would like to achieve with diff:
[image]

to clarify, the first element in each list corresponds to everything with A in the formula, and the second represents B (last rate is just the rate, face is the notional)

Comment: It can't be reproduced. It works normally here and result is `0.3580125817769421`.

Comment: As an aside, why is this an `@classmethod`?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, I forgot to reset the new_rates to be empty. Just a logic in my simulation function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).